# Get the upload url of a file copied to UbuntuOne by Shutter

Tags: ubuntu-one, notify-osd, shutter

I'm using [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) to export screenshots into a folder which is synced with Ubuntu One. Shutter helpfully marks these files as public, and I get a notification (via NotifyOSD) that the file was uploaded and is available at a particular URL.

The issue is that this information is useless because the URL is a random string and Notify [doesn't allow interactions](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/253), such as copying from a notification.

Is there any way to:

- copy the URL from the notification, or
- have Shutter provide that information in a more-accessible way?

Answer (score 2):

It's also automatically copied to the clipboard...